# What is a compute node?

Tags: c#

I understand this may be a very juvenile question, but I'm learning about linked lists in C#, and they keep referencing Nodes, which I somewhat understand at an intuitive level, but I've never gotten a formal explanation of what exactly a node is, especially in this context, can someone give me a rundown on the definition of a node in moderately plain english?

I've read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.computecluster.node(v=vs.85).aspx but it doesn't help much as it uses other concepts/jargon that I don't quite understand just yet.

Thanks!

Comment: "node" in a linked list is only a tiny bit related to a compute node.  You're probably looking for the terminology of graphs, nodes, and edges.

Comment: Linked list nodes and compute nodes have nothing whatsoever to do with each other, aside from both being called nodes.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, to be honest I'm a complete beginner, so even when you reference graphs and edges, I'm not quite sure what those mean either. I'll have to start googling hard haha. Thank you for the tip though! I'll start digging

Comment: @EricLippert interesting, ok so I'm already off on the wrong track? haha

Comment: @EricLippert goes a bit too far in trivializing the connection: Both linked lists and computer networks lend themselves to being modeled by graph theory, which is why both use the word node. And linked list arrangements of computers/computing resources are not uncommon, e.g. pipelines (with no cycle) or token rings (with cycles).

Comment: @BenVoigt You make a good point, which I shall expand into an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get a whiteboard.

Draw a bunch of boxes.

Connect them together with lines.

Maybe put some labels in the boxes and the lines.

Maybe put some arrows on the lines too.

What you've drawn is called a "graph".  A graph consists of *nodes* -- the boxes -- and *edges* which connect them together.   Nodes are also sometimes called "vertices".

Pretty much every problem in representing data reduces to some kind of graph.

You want to find the best route between cities?  Make a graph where the nodes are cities, the edges are roads, and the question is "what's the shortest path consisting of edges between these two nodes?"

You want to design a data center?  Design it as a graph where the nodes are computers and the edges are network cables connecting them.

And so on.

A linked list is simply a very, very, *very* simple graph.  A linked list is just a graph where:

- Every linked list has a node called "empty", or "null" that has zero outgoing edges.
- Every non-empty node in a linked list has one outgoing edge
- Exactly one node in a linked list has zero incoming edges
- There is no path from a node to itself. (AKA "acyclic")

So

```
1 --->  2 ---->   3 ---->   empty
```

is a linked list where 1, 2, 3, empty are the nodes, and the edges are notated by the arrows.  Notice that this meets the definition of a linked list; empty has no outgoing arrows, 1 has no incoming arrows, and every other node has one outgoing and one incoming arrow.

Now imagine relaxing the conditions of a linked list.

An acyclic graph where there is exactly one node with zero incoming edges (called the root) and every other node has exactly one incoming edge is called a "tree".  Every linked list is a tree, but not every tree is a linked list:

```
   1 
 /   \
 |   |
 v   v
 2   3
```

that's a tree, but not a linked list.

If we consider graphs where there are no cycles, but also no restrictions on what edges we can add, then we have a *directed acyclic graph*, or DAG.  Every tree is a DAG; not every DAG is a tree. For example:

```
 1         2 --->  3   <----  4
```

is a DAG, but not a linked list or a tree.

And so on.  Graph theory is a HUGE subject and foundational to computer science. Like I said, almost every problem in representing data can be conceived of as some kind of graph, so the concept of "node" recurs *everywhere* in programming.

Comment: Wow thank you, this actually helps tremendously. I'm that much of a beginner it seems. Much appreciated.

Comment: @glitchwizard: If you're going to be a programmer, get used to drawing boxes with lines between them; it's a fundamental skill!

Comment: Will do! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`Node` in a `LinkedList` is nothing but the byte/bit( memory chunk). It consists of two parts:

**Data** − Each node of a linked list can store a data.

**Address** − Each node of a linked list contains an address to the next node, called "Next".

The first node of a Linked List is referenced by a pointer called Head.

Read [article-1](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-linked-lists-c) & [article-2](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/linked-list-implementation-in-c-sharp/) for more details about linked list and its implementation in C#.